# Get key{index} prop from .map function in react of the elemenet being clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following code

```
const Component = () => {

  const [Clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (prop, e) => {
    console.log(prop);
  }

  return (
    <div>
       {arrayCard.map((item, i) => {
          return (<Card 
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.getAttribute('akey'), e)}
            src={item} 
            akey={i}  />) 
       })}
    </div>
  );
```

and This is my card component

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'

const Card = (props) => {

   return (
    <div>
       <button  onClick={props.onClick} >
         <Image
               src={props.src}
               alt="Card Pic"
               width={80}
               height={80}
         />
       </button>
    </div>     
   );
}
```

As you can see, I have a .map function which gets values from an array and makes card elements. What I want to do is get the specific element being clicked so I thought if I pass a key value I can get the exact element being clicked.

The problem is when I want to get the value of the key prop with the e.target.getAttrinute('akey') returns null. If I do it with the src it works.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: You pass some prop `akey` to `Card` component, but how it related to the `button` onClick event?

Comment: the component return a multiple render of the `card` component, that is how is related

Comment: doing this `handleClick(e.target.getAttribute(i)` I still get nulls onClick()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the item's `index` (that's what usually done):

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const handleClick = (index, e) => {
    console.log(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.arrayCard.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index} onClick={(e) => handleClick(index, e)} src={item} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I can't mark it as correct yet because i have to wait 5 minutes, but can you tell me why this is working? how is the Card element saving that index value without passing a prop? thanks

Comment: There is a closure (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `index` value for each `onClick` function passed to every `Card` component.